# Extra files while compiling typescript code using tsc command

Tags: typescript, tsc, tsconfig

I created a new node development environment, installed the typescript npm module using the command.`npm i --save-dev -g typescript`

I created a app.ts file
app.ts

```
console.log("Hello World")
```

I tried to compile it using

```
tsc --extendedDiagnostics app.ts
```

I got the following output

```
Files:                         6
Lines:                     24817
Nodes:                    111373
Identifiers:               41046
Symbols:                   27913
Types:                      8269
Memory used:              78854K
Assignability cache size:  33122
Identity cache size:           2
Subtype cache size:            0
I/O Read time:             0.01s
Parse time:                0.46s
Program time:              0.48s
Bind time:                 0.31s
Check time:                1.23s
transformTime time:        0.01s
commentTime time:          0.00s
I/O Write time:            0.00s
printTime time:            0.01s
Emit time:                 0.02s
Total time:                2.04s
```

Notice that the number of files here is 6. But I am compiling only one file i.e app.ts
Can someone explain me what the other extra files are here?

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess but I'd say this files count includes not only your `.ts` but also the default `.d.ts` libraries.